# Python string and list manipulation

Tags: python, string, list

I am new to Python and I'm confused when it comes to manipulating string and list at the same time.

Example:

```
for a in range(1, 5):
    print "Values of a is :"
print a
```

I am getting

```
values of a is :
values of a is :
values of a is :
values of a is :
4
```

can you please help me to get something like

```
value of a is :
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Check your indentation of `print a`. Infact, I am surprised how this is even compiling.

Comment: Please check out the [official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
print "Value of a is :"

for a in range(1, 5):
    print a
```

What goes inside the loop gets repeated. So, you need to have `print "Value of a is :"` before the loop.

Comment: @FopacDemamo if Noob's answer works for you, you should accept his answer as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

While Noob's answer isn't wrong, I think what you're trying to do is this:

```
for a in range(1, 5):
    print "Values of a is :"
    print a
```

You can also put it on one line like this:

```
for a in range(1, 5):
    print "Values of a is :", a
```

Comment: I think he wants **Values of a is :** just once.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the nicely edited version of the question with the code block at the bottom. You're right, please ignore mine. :)